# Can I publish analysis of semi open data

Tags: legal

If data is open for personal non commercial use, can I analyse that data and blog about it?

I'm part of a community that uses Zend as its paltform. The API is open so I can read all the community posts, and the site TOS allows personal use of that data. I'm planning to analyse the community posts and blog about my findings - ie what subjects are important, how many posts over time that kind of thing.

There's nothing in the TOS which precludes this, but there is a lot of restrictions around not republishing the content. My plan isn't to republish the content, only my derived analysis from that content.

Comment: That seems like an excellent question for Zend customer service.

Comment: Zend is just the platform - it's the TOS of our community and also what I'm really looking for is precedent from a similar situation